# Private Wishlist vanishes after sharing

Tags: ee-1.13, wishlist

I have enabled multilple wishlists from Magento EE Admin. When a private wishlist is been shared through wishlist share, products are removed from that wishlist after completing the process. While the products don't vanishes on public wishlist. Any one experienced this behaviour before?
Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that when creating the wishlists via the admin section the store id is set to 0

Comment: It seems there was core bug. Issue resolved with a patch. @DavidManners

Comment: @Roney which patch? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @dchayka I dont remember correctly, but you will get the patch if you contact magento support.

Comment: @Roney I had an issue with wishlist not working once you click on "add items to cart" from the email received. I fixed this, if this is the same issue you're experienced I could post my answer here.

Comment: @dchayka you can post your answer. I hope it will be useful to every one. :)